# org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.bnd.BndUtils and IOException: Pipe closed

Tags: java, io, osgi, apache-karaf

What is this all about? How could I fix karaf startup error?

```
2015-03-25 12:05:48,995 | ERROR | Thread-69                      | aQute.lib.osgi.Jar                                   33 | Exception in thread "Thread-69"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot write resource: META-INF/IBM930ByteToChar.dat :415620: exception: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.writeResource(Jar.java:302)[2:org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap:1.3.5]
    at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.write(Jar.java:211)[2:org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap:1.3.5]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.bnd.BndUtils$1.run(BndUtils.java:174)[2:org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap:1.3.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [bug](https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXURL-265) that is already fixed in new version of Karaf